# How to send data from controller which is acceptable format to Highstock?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

I am new to Highstock, am not able to plot the graph.
    I am sending an AJAX request to get the graph data.I am returning List of X-Axis Data, and List of Y-Axis Data, I also used Map but the values are coming like {1420051860000=101}, which is not acceptable format in Highstock.

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
 $.ajax({  url: 'getData',
           dataType : 'json',
           type: 'GET'
           success: function (data) {

        var xAxisdata= data.xAxisData;
        var yAxisData=data.yAxisData;
        //converting two arrays to two-dimesional array, It's not working
         var jarray = [];
         for (var i=0; i<xAxisdata.length && i<yAxisdata.length; i++){
             jarray[i] = [xAxisdata[i], [yAxisdata[i]]];
             }
    //Getting these values for X and Y values   
var xAxisdata=[1420051860000,1420052160000,1420052460000,1420052760000,1420053060000,....];
var yAxisdata=[100,110,112,113,110,112,111,110,115,116,114,114,110,114,112,113,110,....];
//Creates chart
var chart =new Highcharts.StockChart({
            chart: {
                   renderTo: "container",
                   zoomType: 'x'
               },
            rangeSelector : {
                selected : 1,
                inputEnabled: $('#container').width() > 280
            },
            title : {
                text : 'AAPL Stock Price'
            },
            credits: {
                  enabled: false
              },
            xAxis: {
                    title: {
                       text: 'Time'
                   },
                   type: 'datetime',
                    labels:{
                          formatter:function(){
                              return Highcharts.dateFormat('%H<br/>%d<br/>%m<br/>%Y',this.value);
                          }
                      },
                   },
                   yAxis: {
                       title: {
                           text: "Stock "
                       },
                       lineWidth: 1,
                       min:0,
                       gridLineWidth: 0

                   },

            series : [{
                name : 'AAPL',
                showInLegend: true,
                data : jarray,
                marker : {
                    enabled : true,
                    radius : 3
                }
            }]
        });
        }
        });
} );
```

And also facing issue with Months, in javaScript the months are starting from 0 to 11, But in java starts from 1. If the month is JAN-2014, it showing FEB-2014.

Suggest me the best way to plot the graph using JSON Response.

Comment: here in JSFIddle http://jsfiddle.net/C7xw9/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close, there's just a little issue with the format of your array you've built.

Try to use

```
  var jarray = [];
     for (var i=0; i<xAxisdata.length && i<yAxisdata.length; i++){
         jarray[i] = [xAxisdata[i], yAxisdata[i]];
         }
```

Just remove the outer square brackets on **[** yAxisdata[i] **]**

Like in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C7xw9/4/)